# Posible error de aplicación web antigua al cambiar del protocolo HTTP al HTTPS

Tags: php, http, https

Una de las aplicaciones web que se gestionan en mi empresa es bastante antigua (tiene al menos 13 años) y no se ha actualizado apenas en todo ese tiempo. Recientemente la han pasado del protocolo HTTP a HTTPS, pero en apariencia todo seguía funcionando correctamente. Recientemente nos ha llegado una incidencia de uno de los clientes indicando que una funcionalidad de la aplicación ha dejado de responder, pero al probarlo en la máquina virtual donde hacemos pruebas (que todavía usa HTTP) he comprobado que nos funciona correctamente. Sin embargo en su máquina, efectivamente, no muestra los datos solicitados por el cliente. Esta incidencia nos llegó recientemente, aunque el cambio a HTTPS fue hace meses, pero cabe la posibilidad de que en esos meses no hayan usado esa utilidad concreta y de que se hayan dado cuenta ahora.

La página está construida con HTML, CSS, PHP 3.0. y tiene alguna pequeña cosa en AJAX. La base de datos está en Access.

Desgraciadamente yo me dedico al desarrollo en escritorio y apenas tengo competencias en web, por lo que me cuesta especialmente hacerme cargo de un problema con una aplicación tan antigua y con tanto código deprecado. ¿Es posible que el mero hecho de haber cambiado el protocolo a HTTPS haya sido la causa de un único error en la aplicación (al menos el único que se ha encontrado en los meses que lleva así) o no debería afectar?

La verdad es que si el problema no fuese este no sabría ni por dónde empezar, ya que tengo muy pocos conocimientos de web y no queda nadie en la empresa que haya trabajado con esta aplicación, ya que es muy antigua y lleva años sin modificaciones.

Me ayudaríais mucho si pudieseis resolverme la duda sobre los protocolos o darme alguna pista de hacia dónde tirar.

Muchas gracias.

**Editado:**

Al entrar en la consola en el ordenador del cliente me salen los siguientes mensajes:

> Se ha bloqueado la carga del contenido activo mixto "http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.0/build/assets/skins/sam/skin.css"
>
> Se ha bloqueado la carga del contenido activo mixto "http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.5.0/build/utilities/utilities.js"

Por lo que he podido ver, al meter referencias HTTP en aplicaciones que funcionen HTTPS se bloquea este contenido (contenido mixto) por no cumplir las normas de seguridad de HTTPS. Tendré que tirar por ahí para ver si puedo sustituirlo o adaptarlo de algún modo...

Comment: Puede que la web este haciendo referencia directa a un vinculo como `http://localhost/project/...` y sea simplemente colocar el `https` pero es solo una idea, tu pregunta es muy abierta y sin ver el código es muy difícil resolverlo.

Comment: Gracias a lo que dijiste me di cuenta de que deben de ir por ahí los tiros, mil gracias!

Answer (score -1):

el problema no se ocasiona por el cambio de protocolo de **HTTP** a **HTTPS**, ya que el **protocolo HTTPS** se encargan únicamente de garantizar que la comunicación entre el sitio web y el navegador sea encriptada. A diferencia del **HTTP** que se encarga de verificar seguridad ni tampoco guarda información sobre sesiones o comandos ejecutados anteriormente por lo que utiliza **cookies** lo que permite almacenar en el servidor la información del cliente y eso lo hace menos seguro. Por ende los protocolos **http y https** representan diferentes alternativas pero si pensamos en la seguridad de un sitio web y en cifrado de datos, estaríamos hablando de implementar un protocolo **https**.

Saludos.